# Merging two DataFrames with different number of key elements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing datasets concerning the 2016 election.  They are data on demographics and voting results by U.S. county.  I want to narrow down the counties to the ones that strongly support Trump. So, I created a new DataFrame using the by county election results dataset that contains only counties that went for Trump by over 75%.  I've done this like so:

```
strong_Trump = election_data2[election_data2['per_gop'] > 0.75]
strong_Trump.set_index('County')
```

Now I have another completely different dataset that gives demographic info by county but no info on the election.  How would I merge these two datasets into one DataFrame so that it only contains election and demographic info on the counties Trump won with over 75% of the vote?

Comment: You need an inner join of the two dataframes. Please include sample data if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd put even a small slice of the dataframes or datasets in my question.  They are large and jupyter notebook files don't translate well in here.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in order to join both dataframes.
If the other DataFrame is called *demographic_df* and assuming it has a column *Country* as well then you can use an inner join:

```
election_and_demographic_df = strong_Trump.merge(right=demographic_df, how='inner', left_on='Country', right_on='Country')
```

If both have the index set to the country column then you can use `left_index=True` and `right_index=True` instead of `left_on` and `right_on`.